# confused about a nested loop having linear complexity(Big-Oh = O(n)) but I worked it to be logarithmic

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Computing complexity and Big o of an algorithm

> T(n) = 5n log n + 3log n + 2 // to the base 2 big o = o(n log n)

```
for(int x = 0,i = 1;i <= N;i*=2)
{
    for(int j = 1 ;j <= i ;j++)
    {
        x++;
    }
}
```

The Big o expected was linear where as mine is logarithmic

Answer (score 3):

Your Big-Oh analysis is not correct. While it is true that the outer loop is executed log *n* times, the inner loop is linear in *i* at each iteration.

If you count the total number of iterations of the inner loop, you will see that the whole thing is linear:

The inner loop will do `‍1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + (the last power of 2 <= N)` iterations. This sum will be between `N` and `2*N`, which makes the whole loop linear.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain why your analysis is wrong.

It is clear that inner loop will execute `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k` times where `k` is the biggest integer which satisfies equation [image]. This implies that upper bound for `k` is

[image]

Without loss of generality we can take upper bound for `k` and assume that `k` is integer, complexity equals to 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + [image] = which is geometric series so it is equal to

[image]

Therefore in O notation it is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should notice that your analysis is not logarithmic! As `N \log N` is not logarithmic.

Also, the time complexity is `T(n) = sum_{j = 0}^{log(n)} 2^j` (as the value of `i` duplicated each time). Hence, `T(n) = 2^(log(N) +  1) - 1 = 2N - 1 = \Theta(N)`.

Comment: I think I more confused so the outer loop have no effect on the inner one because I couldn't understand how you get rid of the outer loop log complexity